# Unselectable does not work on webkit

Tags: jquery, input, unselect

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).val('example');
    $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on').css('user-select', 'none').on('startselect', false);
});
```

When I try to select field value on Chrome or Opera, I'm able to do that.
On Firefox and IE it's fine.

Is there any way to disable text selecting in input field?

IE 10, Chrome 30, Opera 17.

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/VmDDY/

Comment: I believe the event is `selectstart`, not `startselect`. Not sure if that will solve your problem though.

Comment: i think this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/user-select) tells that the feature is not supported by the browsers you've mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).val('example');
    $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on')
           .addClass('unselectable').on('startselect', false);
    //add class ------^
});
```

**Opera** does not supports [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/user-select)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all the correct CSS variations:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

but this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/user-select) tells that the feature is not supported by the browsers you've mentioned